# Do I need to use BluePrint's ie.css if I use JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, blueprint-css

I am still new to JQuery and BluePrint. BluePrint recommends adding the following lines in HTML pages headers to tackle Internet Explorer related issues:

```
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
    <![endif]-->
```

But, is this really necessary if one uses JQuery to manipulate pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

jQuery does not patch poor IE CSS support out-of-the-box. The Blueprint file attempts to 'reset' IE so that when you apply your own styles, they look in IE more like they should do (i.e. how they look in compliant browsers).